# How to work with UTF-8 numeric encoded from Zend_Json in JS?

Tags: php, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using Zend_Json (actually, I'm using ajaxContext with automatic json serialization), and I need to send Japanese chars encoded in Utf-8.

I receive from my ajax request such data :

```
{"comments":"\\u65e5\\u672c\\u6700"}
```

Now, what can I do with that? to "translate" it into readable chars in my html page?

thank you

Comment: Try disabling magic quotes, and Zend_Json (actually json_decode) will automatically transform it into valid UTF-8 sequences usable in a html page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion, however: user@host:~$ php -i | grep "magic"
magic_quotes_gpc => Off => Off
magic_quotes_runtime => Off => Off
magic_quotes_sybase => Off => Off

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery json parser for decode chars.

```
jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

This function convert encoded chars to readable chars in html.